# Wordpress media custom tab without iframe

Tags: wordpress

I need a custom media tab, that im using as widget area so that the admin user can add custom made templates.

But I'm having trouble inserting anything into the text editor because the tab is inside an iframe.

Is there a way to add a custom media tab without the content of it being inside a iframe?

Comment: I am getting your question easily so, Let me share more details on same

Comment: Hey, still got those details? :)